# What would happen to the people of kaba in the judgement day?

Tags: day-of-judgement, people

During the judgement day when the world is being shattered what will happen to the kaba? Would the people inside the kaba be saved by Allah?

Comment: I'm afraid you are confusing kaaba with Mekka or the masjid al-Haram. On judgement day we will all be in presence of our Creator waiting for His fair judgement. Any thing else would need strong backup.

Answer (score 1):

The kaba will be destroyed as well. If there were people inside it, they will die. After that, they will be resurrected again. The following verses talk about this event:

> 28:83 (As for) that future abode, We assign it to those who have no
>   desire to exalt themselves in the earth nor to make mischief and the
>   good end is for those who guard (against evil)
>
> 28:84 Whoever brings good, he shall have better than it, and whoever brings
>   evil, those who do evil shall not be rewarded (for) aught except what
>   they did.
>
> 28:85 Most surely He Who has made the Quran binding on you will bring you
>   back to the destination. Say: My Lord knows best him who has brought
>   the guidance and him who is in manifest error.
>
> 28:86 And you did not expect that the Book would be inspired to you, but it
>   is a mercy from your Lord, therefore be not a backer-up of the
>   unbelievers.
>
> 28:87 And let them not turn you aside from the communications of Allah after
>   they have been revealed to you, and call (men) to your Lord and be not
>   of the polytheists.
>
> 28:88 And call not with Allah any other god; **there is no god but He, every
>   thing is perishable but He;** His is the judgment, and to Him you
>   shall be brought back.